# How to use the same function for a button inside a loop?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysqli

I have a homepage where it shows products from the database and I placed an add to cart button that of course will add each specific product to the cart. Currently I have 6 products shown on the page but apparently only the first product can be added to the cart and the rest has a button that does not work.

Upon research it is advised that we cannot use the same id multiple times via JavaScript (I am using id="add-to-cart") and that is what's happening inside the loop therefore only the first item has a working button.

How can I generate specific ID's to each add to cart button on my while loop and how will the script recognize or read each specific id? I am no JavaScript expert.

```
                $result = mysqli_query($bd,$sql2);

            }

            if($result){                
            while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
            $prodID = $row["ID"];

            $prodname= $row["itemname"];
            $prodprice = $row["price"];

            ?>  

                        <h1 class="product"><?php echo $prodname; ?></h1>
                            <p>Price: <span class="price"><?php echo $prodprice; ?></span></p>
                            <br>
                            <a class="btn btn-default add-to-cart cartButtons" id="add-to-cart" input>Add to Cart</a>
                            <p class="info hidethis" style="color:red;"><strong>Item Added to Cart!</strong></p>
```

Here's the script:

```
$('#add-to-cart').on('click',function(){
    $(this).siblings('.info').fadeIn(700).fadeOut(1000);
    var price = $(this).siblings('p').children('.price').html();
    var product = $(this).siblings('.product').html();
    $.post('cart/data.php?q=addtocart',
           {
                price:price,
                product:product,
                qty:1
           }
    );
});
```

Comment: When you cannot use multiple of the same id (because they must be unique!), thats where binding click events to a .class comes in handy.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Per your example, remove your `id="add-to-cart"`, then adjust the jquery click like this:

```
$('.add-to-cart').on('click',function(){ ... });
```

This will give that click event to all buttons set to be of class `add-to-cart`. Since you already use `$(this)` inside your click event function, it is already pulling the details from THAT click, and not others.

Comment: Sir your solution definitely worked. All add to cart buttons are now working for each product. Thank you very much for your help! very much appreciated